# Flurry 4.3.2 linking issues

Tags: ios, flurry

I'm trying to update Flurry from v 4.2.3 to 4.3.2 in my iOS application. I've updated the files, and in Frameworks updated it to use libFlurry_4.3.2.a. However, when I look at the project.pbxproj file, under library search paths in a couple places it includes the local path to the file as well as `"\\\"$(SRCROOT)/[AppName]/Third\\ Party/Flurry\\ Analytics\\\""`.

Will this cause issues if someone else goes to build the code on a different computer? If I remove the local path it doesn't build.

Comment: That's not a local path. `$(SRCROOT)` will evaluate to an absolute path at compile-time.

Comment: There is a local path _in addition to_ $(SRCROOT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I have had similar issues I removed the absolute local path, then removed all of the unnecessary `\` characters. So try changing the search path to `"$(SRCROOT)/[AppName]/Third Party/Flurry Analytics"` and removing the absolute local path.